# Button dot not respond to selector when user touches coordinates outside its superview

Tags: ios

As mentioned in the title, I added a button which have a center that corresponds on the top right point on its superview c.f

[image: image attached].

My problem is when I click on that button outside on it's superview (white view on the image). it does not respond to anything.

Do you know a way to make all this stuff working.

EDIT : Here's my code :

```
UIView * AlertView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, self.frame.size.width-60, self.frame.size.height)];
        AlertView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240 green:240 blue:240 alpha:1];

        UIButton * closebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(AlertImgView.frame.size.width , 50 , 50, 50)];
        [closebtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        closebtn.center = CGPointMake(AlertImgView.frame.size.width, 0);
        [closebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; 
        [AlertView addSubview:close];
```

Regards

Comment: `UIButton` responds only if the touch is also in the superview frame

Comment: oh god ! So may be the solution is to add a larger (invisible) view that will be the Alert's superView ? What do you think ?

Comment: Consider you are adding `superview` to `containerView`. You have to add the UIButton to `containerView` too and you have to check the target of the IBAction: it must be the `UIViewController` that it is the owner of `containerView`

Comment: It's a working solution but that's pretty ugly. For a single alert view, you'll have to manage several instances. But if you're too proud to switch your alert view for a well-coded one, use this trick.

Comment: It is the more faster way, I know it isn't too clean eheh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible this way, cause your alert view captures touches only into its bounds. Maybe you may consider creating a full-custom alert view, or using an already existing alert view library [on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=alertview&ref=opensearch&type=Repositories).

Comment: Nooo, it's impossible to use an already existing one, because I'm pretty proud of what I have done :/

Comment: Really guy? So that's your problem, but using already existing libraries is a good practice (checking licensing before using them and not abusing their usage).

Comment: I've already used many of them, but in that case, my client wants an Alert with close button on the top right of the alertView. So after checking a bunch of libraries, I made this one by my self, and it fits exactly with my client expectations. The only little problem is the only thing that make me sick

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code, its working for me BUT you have to add `closebtn` instead of `close` `( [AlertView addSubview:close];)` to your alertview

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's a little mistake when copying my code. Indeed that works, but if you try to tap on the button outside it's superview frame, nothing will happen